# Качество фотографии при сохранении её в телеграм боте

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, photo

Пишу телеграм бота на Python, который сохраняет фотографии, которые кидает пользователь и сохраняет в БД. При сохранении фотографий, качество заметно падает. Можно ли на это как-то повлиять? Использую библиотеку telebot.
Код:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['document']) 
def save_text(message):
    try:
        src = filepath + '/documents/'
        chat_id = message.chat.id
        file_info = bot.get_file(message.document.file_id)
        downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)
        src += message.document.file_name
        with open(src, 'wb') as new_file:
            new_file.write(downloaded_file)
        bot.reply_to(message, "Текст успешно получен. Спасибо!") 
    except:
        bot.reply_to(message, "Ошибка отправления: "+Exception)
```

Comment: Вы уверены что качество фотографий снижается именно при сохранении фотографий? Возможно сам телеграмм сжимает фотографии? 
Для сохранения качества нужно отправлять фото как документ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, что бы фото не сжималось его надо отправлять как **документ**, а сохраняете Вы правильно.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да а как сделать что бы бот принмал и сжатые файлы?